# Xcode 7.3.1 itself crashes instantly on resymbolicate crash log

Tags: xcode

Xcode 7.3.1 itself crashes instantly on resymbolicate crash log. Do people see this, is there a workaround?
The target name of the app which has the crash log is using non-alpha characters, so the filename of the crash log does too. I'm just guessing that such a thing could be of concern and could be worth looking into later.

Crash log of the Xcode crash.

```
Process:               Xcode [26717]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.3.1 (10188.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-10188001000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       817226719
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [26717]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2016-05-09 13:59:49.452 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        BA41D661-8DBF-03DD-FB21-F8B96CA8C464


Time Awake Since Boot: 260000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        17  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7D1014
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
  5   -[DVTLocalLogSymbolicator _parseToolStandardError:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6   __55-[DVTLocalLogSymbolicator symbolicateLogData:callback:]_block_invoke_3 (in DVTFoundation)
  7   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 12   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called
```

Comment: FYI: Never worked this out. I ended up symbolicating the crash report I had "manually", without opening Xcode.